# "Illegal start of expression" rookie mistake?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I need to know why I'm getting this error on lines 18-21. I'm feeling like it MIGHT be a bracket related issue, but I can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj4_1 {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numb1 =;
    int numb2 =; 
    int div =;
    int remainder =;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    numb1 = reader.nextint();

    System.out.print(numb1);

    System.out.println("Enter another number: ");
    numb2 = reader.nextint();

    System.out.print(numb2);

    if (numb1>numb2){
        div = numb1 / numb2;
        remainder = numb1 % numb2;
    }else{
    if (numb2>numb1) 
        div = numb2 / numb1;
        remainder = numb2 % numb2;  
    }

    System.out.println("The answer quotient is " +div+ "with a remainder of" +remainder);
```

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: A compiler error can't be a runtime error at the same time.

Comment: `int numb1 =;` looks kind of bizarre to me, I think it might be where your problem is

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what if the compiler itself crashed?

Comment: @SamIam it means that you could be running an old version of the code not the actual compiled one.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Then there's the possibility of using Eclipse, which lets you run code even if it doesn't compile - the generated code will throw an exception when it gets to the broken bit :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, look at this:

```
int numb1 =;
```

What are you expecting the initial value to be?

You can declare a variable without assigning it a value, like this:

```
int numb1;
```

... but you can't leave the `=` there without giving a value.

However, I would personally *wait* to declare the variable until you're ready to give it a value:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    // Fixed case of nextInt as well...
    int numb1 = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print(numb1);

    System.out.println("Enter another number: ");
    int numb2 = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print(numb2);

    // etc
}
```

You don't have to declare all the variables at the top of the method, and your code will generally be cleaner if you only declare them where you first need them.

EDIT: There's also this `if` block which is incorrect:

```
if (numb2>numb1)
    div = numb2 / numb1;
    remainder = numb2 % numb2;  
}
```

You've missed out the opening brace, which means you've *effectively* got this:

```
if (numb2>numb1) {
    div = numb2 / numb1;
}
remainder = numb2 % numb2;  
// This closing brace is now dangling!
}
```

You really meant this:

```
if (numb2 > numb1) {
    div = numb2 / numb1;
    remainder = numb2 % numb2;  
}
```

Note that if you regularly compile the code, you won't get this far with so many *different* errors. As soon as you get one compile-time error, you should stop, make sure you understand it, and fix it. That way you'll never be faced with an overwhelming number of problems to try to understand at once. Additionally, you don't need to worry about multiple errors interacting with each other, which can make life much harder.

Comment: I'm prompting for input on the 23rd 28th lines

Comment: @user2267726: Yes, but what do you expect that declaration with an `=` to do?

Comment: There's also `if (numb2>numb1) sentence1; sentence2; }` (no opening bracket).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: True, will mention that.